Cloudflare Workers received 404 error after successful deployment
So I wanted to add a staging environment for development purposes for one of my domains.
Main website that’s under development is working perfectly with Cloudflare workers. I cloned the Git repo that’s currently connected for the domain name and then went to Workers & Pages > Create > Pages > Connect to Git.
After connecting, the logs read “Success: Your site was deployed”
However, when I go to visit the address supplied by Cloudflare it gives me a 404 Error.
I was under the impression once I connected GitHub repo under Workers & Pages, that it’ll deploy a live server automatically and I’ll be charged according to usage.
Apparently that is not the case. How do I get the Cloudflare Workers server to enable for this newly connected repo? Is there a server I have to purchase for the pages.dev URL supplied by Cloudflare to work?


I just created a simple worker without a GitHub connection and the URL/domain came up and was accessible just fine. A couple things to consider:

If you just make a regular worker through the UI, without a GitHub integration, are you able to access it?
If that doesn't, consider looking over the pricing page for workers to see if you've exceeded a free tier amount (although it says there is a free tier option for workers)
If that does work, then check if your build settings are properly configured for the project

